# When using drop-down navbar button in Twitter Bootstrap, it expends and overshadows the content below

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning to use twitter bootstrap. Now, I have successfully created a drop-down button using the `navbar-toggle` collapsed classes. The problem is that whenever I activate the button. It overshadows the `p` element below, as depicted in the pictures below:
[drop-down navbar button not activated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0HYT.png)

[drop-down navbar button expanded overshadowing the element below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlxMr.png)

I have tried using `clear: left`, yet there has been no success.
Here is a code example:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar-default navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light" id="navbar-head">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href= "#" class="navbar-brand pull-left" id="company-brand">Food, LLC</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed xs-visible" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse ">
          <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <a href="#"> <br>Chicken</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> <br>Beef</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"> <br>Sushi</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- Container end  -->
    </nav> <!-- nav header end-->
  </header>

  

  <div><p class="text-center">Our Menu</p></div>
```

The CSS code follows:

```
 #collapsable-nav  a { /* Collapsed nav menu text */
        font-size: 1.5em;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: rgb(213, 216, 32);
    }

    .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle, .navbar-header .icon-bar {
        border: 1px solid #61122f;
    }
    .navbar-header button.navbar-toggle {
        clear: both;
        margin-top: -30px;
    }
```

When the drop-down menu drops down, it overshadows the text `our menu`.I would like it to move down with the drop-down menu.

Can anyone help with that?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example in your question and not a link to a github page https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's the default bootstrap behavior I'm pretty sure.  The user is clicking the menu so it should take priority over the rest of the page.  Do you want other elements to shift when the "hamburger menu" is opened or something?

Comment: Yes, I would like other elements to shift downward when the list is dropped down.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by not specifying the height in the Nav-bar.

```css
#navbar-head {
    background-color: rgb(212, 145, 20);
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    /* height: 72px; */
}
```